# Options for simple geolocation feature?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, geolocation

I need to add location features to a classifieds app. Basically,

- Users must search for classifieds by city and state
- Results should include nearby city and states (e.g. results within 50 miles)

I am clueless about the APIs I could use, if any. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Have you researched/tried something already?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out [NGeo](https://github.com/danludwig/NGeo).

Disclaimer: I am the author of NGeo.

Nuget package is also [available here](https://preview.nuget.org/packages/NGeo).